# Python dict comprehension on a Django Queryset

Tags: python, django, django-orm, dictionary-comprehension

In my project i have a Django ORM query for manage some data:

```
    var_results = VarsResults.objects.filter(
        id_res__read_date__range=(start_d, end_d),
        id_res__proj_code=pr_code,
        var_id__is_quarterly=False
    ).select_related(
        "id_res",
        "var_id"
    ).values(
        "id_res__read_date",
        "id_res__unit_id",
        "id_res__device_id",
        "id_res__proj_code",
        "var_val"
    )
```

well, my query return an Queryset object containing data i need.
My problem is that the var_val is a string representation of a dict and i, instead of that value (for example '[54321, 98]') i would convert it using my conversion function

```
def decode_value(original value):
    ...
    return <converted value>
```

i would call directly my decode_value function in my queryset creation like this:

```
var_results = VarsResults.objects.filter(
        id_res__read_date__range=(start_d, end_d),
        id_res__proj_code=pr_code,
        var_id__is_quarterly=False
    ).select_related(
        "id_res",
        "var_id"
    ).values(
        "id_res__read_date",
        "id_res__unit_id",
        "id_res__device_id",
        "id_res__proj_code",
        decode_value(var_val)
    )
```

but i get an error:

> var_val is not defined

so i thinked about create using a python dict comprehension a dedicated dict stating from my queryset with all queryset field and var_val field converted but i don't know how achieve this.

Can somaone help me about dinamicaly value editing in django ORM queryset object creation or in a dict comprehension from a Queryset object?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to post-proces the result.

Comment: Thanks so mutch, i would post process using a dict comprehension on my Queryset object but i don't know how can i create one with all field of my queryset + one for var_val coversion data

Comment: It would be better for you to consider the following question instead: "Should I be storing arrays as strings inside a database?", you would benefit from researching a bit on [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) as it is very clear that your database schema is not appropriate for your use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
from django.db.models import F

var_results = VarsResults.objects.filter(
        id_res__read_date__range=(start_d, end_d),
        id_res__proj_code=pr_code,
        var_id__is_quarterly=False
    ).select_related(
        "id_res",
        "var_id"
    ).annotate(
      var_val_decoded = decode_value(F('var_val'))).values(
        "id_res__read_date",
        "id_res__unit_id",
        "id_res__device_id",
        "id_res__proj_code",
        "var_val_decoded"
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i run i get :   var_val_decoded = decode_value(F('var_val')).values(
AttributeError: 'CombinedExpression' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Hi, missed one parenthesis, try now

Comment: Have you tried my updated snipped @ManuelSanti?